# Rails gem "friendly_id": How to get a live preview of the slug, before its object is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, slug, friendly-id, live-preview

Using the Rails gem "friendly_id", is it possible to get a "live preview" of the slug to be created? Before the object is saved, that is (and to be returned while typing using an ajax request)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FriendyId author here.

FriendlyId internally uses the private `set_slug` to do this. This method is invoked via a `before_validation` callback. If for some reason you do not wish to call `valid?`, you can invoke the `set_slug` method via `send`, or define a method in your model which invokes it:

```
instance = ModelClass.new
instance.send(:set_slug)

# or
class ModelClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def generate_slug_preview
    set_slug
  end
end
```

However, note that bypassing or ignoring validations is often a bad idea. For example, if your model included a validation on the `name` field, and then you used that field as the basis of the slug, then you are previewing a slug that will never actually be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/test/slugged_test.rb ...

```
  m1 = model_class.new :name => "a b c d"
  m1.valid?
  assert_equal "a-b-c-d", m1.slug
```

Looks like it's just `.slug`. Per other tests, you don't need the `create` - a `new` will do. So your strategy is:

- add an `onchange` handler to the text field
- each time the user changes it, use Ajax to send the current value to the server
- `new` an instance of your model, with the name or whatever set to the value Ajax sent
- call `slug`, and send the result back to the web page
- display it in the web page

All that is standard Ajax stuff, with nothing to do with `friendly_id`. But it all makes me wonder if - because you show the slug to the user - `friendly_id` will let you then edit the slug, the way high-end blogs do.

And you probably must call `valid?` first.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, calling something like ```Article.new(title: "A new article").slug``` returns nil...

Comment: Your solution is correct (it returned nil b/c my model has validations which failed b/c I only passed it the one value for the attribute needed for the generation of the slug). So, I'll have to make all validations conditional, i.e. ```validates :name, unless: :on_the_fly``` and then add to the model ```attr_accessor :on_the_fly``` and sumit a ```true``` value for it, each time the user ajax-submits their value-to-be-slugged. (On the other hand, this doesn't seem safe since it allows anyone to bypass validation.)

Comment: Tx but that solution sucks. Rails validations suck because validations belong on a Form, not on a Model. (Different users, seeing different forms, could experience different validations, for example.) So friendly_id should not require the .valid? call to pass just to generate a slug.

Comment: Calling `Article.new(title: "A new article").slug` returns nil because you didn't invoke `valid?`, so the slug was never generated. Validations are actually important to the slug generation because in many cases the input into the slugging method comes from a field with validations, so it absolutely should be a part of the validation process. You can work around that as I described in my answer here, in the event you're generating a slug from input that doesn't have any validations associated with it.

Comment: Point. I should have more carefully detached why Rails validations suck from why friendly_id needs them.